# Is there a difference between Enumerable#each and Enumerable#each_entry in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, each

The [Enumerable documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html) does not state explicitly that `each` is an alias for `each_entry`, but the description of `each_entry` matches exactly what I would expect from `each`.

In the examples of both answers new classes are defined, which implement the `Enumerable` module and define the `each` method.

Can someone give an example of a built-in class, like `Array` or `Hash`, which behaves differently with `each` and `each_entry`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are different. Using the examples from RDoc:

```
class Foo
  include Enumerable
  def each
    yield 1
    yield 1, 2
    yield
  end
end

Foo.new.each_entry{|o| p o}
# =>
1
[1, 2]
nil

Foo.new.each{|o| p o}
# =>
1
1
nil

Foo.new.each{|*o| p o}
# =>
[1]
[1, 2]
[]
```

The difference is that `each_entry` passes all elements to the sole block variable by behaving differently depending on the number of elements passed in a single iteration: if none, it takes it as `nil`, if one, it takes that parameter, otherwise, it puts them in an array. `each`, on the other hand, passes to the sole block variable only the first object that is passed in each iteration.

Comment: Wow, thank you. One more thing, though: if `each` "only takes the first object that is passed in each iteration" how comes it gives the output in the third example, when used with the splat operator? Can we say - in order to make `each` accept not only the first element given in a single iteration - use the splat operator.

Comment: To be more precise, it passes only the first object to the first block variable. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @sawa:

```
class Alphabet
  include Enumerable
  AZ = ('a'..'z')
  def each
    AZ.each{|char| yield char}
  end
end

p Alphabet.new.each_entry #<Enumerator: #<Alphabet:0x000000028465c8>:each_entry>
p Alphabet.new.each       #in `block in each': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
```

Comment: This is more expressive answer... Liked it... Good research